# Где взять многопоточный python прокси чекер?

Tags: python, proxy

Нужен Proxy Checker на python
Что-то не могу найти нормальный прокси чекер на python:
— проверка на то что прокси "живой"
— проверка на страну прокси
— бесплатный
—работа в многопотоке ( нужно чекать 10000 прокси)

Возможно есть готовые варианты самому мне врятли нормальный удастся написать?

Comment: https://github.com/pythonism/proxy-checker